# Can we take famous questions out of the "review audit" system?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, review-audit

Earlier I saw a first post come through the review system titled "Are mathematical articles on Wikipedia reliable?" Now, since I'm genuinely reviewing and not thinking that the system is throwing fake situations in my face (It shows a total score of 0 for the question and maybe 1 comment) I click to flag as a duplicate since recently there was a successful question on the same topic.

Apparently this *was* the question I thought it was duplicating and I immediately failed the audit. However, if such a question were to legitimately come through the system, flagging as duplicate would be the correct action, right? I think either a.) we should not have famous questions as audit material, since the audit system makes it look like a distinct (but still duplicate) question or b.) allow us to flag as a duplicate, because that's the most realistic action to take.

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/202185) is the failed review.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but at the same time, you should try to not expend too much energy on this automatic annoyances. I am in favour of option c): allow us to click "This is a stupid review question, give me a real one." We could call this option "Dracarys".

Comment: It is worth noting that, barring a (human) moderator intervention, failed reviews have little effect. Since us mods can distinguish between a bad review question and a bad reviewer, there is little harm.

Answer (score 3):

If, in your opinion, a question is truly a duplicate of another post, and that other post has at least one upvoted answer, then mark it as a duplicate.

As far as getting busted by the bot, no harm done, and I'll bet you would have noticed if the bot let you go further that they were the same question. I usually go to the proposed duplicate and the original post (by right click on titles) and compare both posts side by side carefully before touching any buttons. Skip is another popular option for me. Keep up the good work.

With regards to the (bug) tag: It is definitely not a bug.

As a feature request, very few people that will read this can actually implement your feature, but as I understand it, those that can most assuredly will read your post.

Comment: I disagree that this is not a bug. Clicking the "close" button is not the same as making a choice about the question, so it is a bug that the review is failed already at that point.

Comment: When I say not a bug, I mean that the process worked by as it was designed to work, not that it is good design.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It's not a bug, in the sense that the review system was designed to have exactly this behaviour; see Shog9's [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179770) from when this came up on capital-M Meta.